# EPPlus Library, save as

Tags: c#, wpf, epplus

Using EPPlus, it's easy to save a document to a predefined path, but I need to save to diferent paths everytime, so I need EPPlus to show the standard save dialog.

My code can create an Excel file from a datatable, formats it a little bit, and saves it on the specified location:

```
            DirectoryInfo outputDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\user001\Downloads");
            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\Crit.xlsx");

            if (newFile.Exists) {newFile.Delete();}

            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Crit");
                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtCrit, true);
                ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns(0);
                ws.Cells["A1:Z1"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                ws.Cells["A1:Z1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                pck.Save();
           }
```

How can I show the dialogbox to manually chose a destination folder?
I tried with pck.SaveAs, but I can't make it work, and there is not much information about this...

UPDATE:
The App works when executed from inside the Project, or from the server. Crashes if executed with a shourcut or copy/pasting the exe to my desktop.

```
string mydocpath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

      try {
                DirectoryInfo outputDir = new DirectoryInfo(mydocpath);
                FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\Requerimientos_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm") + ".xlsx");

                if (newFile.Exists) { newFile.Delete(); }

                using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Requerimientos");
                    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtReque, true);
                    ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns(0);
                    ws.Cells["A1:Z1"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                    ws.Cells["A1:Z1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

                    var dlg = new SaveFileDialog { FileName = "Requerimientos_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm"), DefaultExt = ".xlsx", Filter = "Excel Sheet (.xlsx)|*.xlsx", InitialDirectory = mydocpath };
                    var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
                    if (result == true)
                    {
                        using (var stream = dlg.OpenFile())
                        {
                            pck.SaveAs(stream);
                            OpenDialog("File Created", "Export");
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `SaveFileDialog`?

Comment: That works on WPF? Can't find it.

Comment: Its on win32 library, WPF does not have a savefiledialog per se. But I'm working on a WPF project and I use that library.

Comment: Ok, added it and seems to be working. But I do not know how to connect the savedialog and what I get from EPPlus.

Comment: `SaveAs` accepts a stream or a FileInfo object. You can create a FileInfo using the selectd filename or you can open a stream to the target file with `SaveFileDialog.OpenFile()`

Comment: Are you coping just the EXE to your local pc or the entire build folder?  The exe alone will probably not be enough since you will need any referenced dlls (like Epplus.dll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF provides the standard file dialogs through the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace. You can use [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog.aspx) to display a dialog box and select or create a file to save to.

Once you have selected a file, you pass create a FileInfo from the path and pass it to `SaveAs`, eg:

```
// Configure save file dialog box
var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog 
              {
                  FileName = "NewSheet", // Default file name
                  DefaultExt = ".xlsx", // Default file extension
                  Filter = "Excel Sheet (.xlsx)|*.xlsx" // Filter files by extension
              }

// Show save file dialog box
var result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Process save file dialog box results
if (result == true)
{
    // Save document
        string filename = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName);
        package.SaveAs(newFile);
}
```

Or you can use [SaveFileDialog.OpenStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog.openfile.aspx) to have the dialog itself create a stream to save to:

```
if (result == true)
{
        // Save document
        using(var stream=dlg.OpenStream())
        {
            package.SaveAs(stream);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I am facing a when I try to run if from my own computer. The Project is stored in a server, and when I execute it from the own Project (from the server) it works. Is I créate a shourtcut or copy/paste the App to my desktop, it craches when the sabe dialog should open. Look at my update to see the final code.

Comment: @Piston what is the error? What is the *full* exception, as returned by `Exception.ToString()` ?

Comment: How can I get that in this case? The App just crashes with the typical "Program stopped working" window. Please, see updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SaveFileDialog`:

```
private static bool? saveExcelPackageDialog(string fileName, string workingDirectory, byte[] rawBinaryObject)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = EXCEL_FILTER_FILE_DIALOG;
    sfd.InitialDirectory = workingDirectory;
    sfd.FileName = fileName;

    bool? result = sfd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(sfd.FileName, rawBinaryObject);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sfd.FileName);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You have to use it like that:

```
saveExcelPackageDialog(newFile.FullName, outputDir.FullName, pkg.GetAsByteArray());
```

Comment: You don't need to generate the sheet in memory. This doubles memory usage without any benefit, and simply wastes memory if the user cancels. `SaveAs` can save the contents to a file or stream.